# Have another class control a picture[ ] on the main form

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I tried to create a class "bgcar" for race cars that is responsible for handling all variables related to some race cars, one of those variables are pictures of the race car, to be placed on the main form. All variables speed position location gasoline etc. work (but I removed that from below).

However loading and updating the images turns out to be problematic.
I tried a few variations on the code below but so far nothing works.

I can imagine one would think why don't simply write it all in the Main form, however I don't want to create lots of form variables, I want a class to be able to handle it self and with an classtype.update(). update the main form.
Which is a winform application.

```
namespace game
{ 
public class Main:Form
  {
    bgcar racecars;
  
    public Main()
    {
      racecars = new bgcar();
      racecars.update

      //to add later
      //traficlights.update
      //people.update
    }
  }
class bgcar
{
  public PictureBox[] wagon;
  public bgcar() //constructor
  {
    wagon = new PictureBox[2];

    //below wont work.
    //while on the main form 
    // picturebox1.image new bitmap(game.Properties.Resources.SportwagonA)
    //works, proving it does exist in the resource file.
    wagon[0].image = new Bitmap(game.Properties.Resources.SportwagonA);
    wagon[1].image = new Bitmap(game.Properties.Resources.SportwagonB);
  }
  public void update()
  {
    //displaying those images is also a problem
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x = rnd.next(100);
    int y = rnd.next(100);
    Wagon[0].location = new point (x,y);

    int x = rnd.next(100);
    int y = rnd.next(100);
    Wagon[1].location = new point (x,y);
  }
 }
}
```

==update
Going to eat first, I'm now thinking of creating on my Main :form
a `public PictureBox[] sportcars`, then have in my mainform a routine that
does something like: sportscar = bgcar.wagon;   not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the **Form** into your class so you can add the controls to it:

```
public Main()
{
  racecars = new bgcar(this); // <--- Pass the Form in
  racecars.update();
}
```

Here's an updated version of the Class:

```
}

public class bgcar
{

    private Form frm;
    private List<PictureBox> wagon;
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public bgcar(Form frm) //constructor receives the Form
    {
        this.frm = frm; // store Form reference for possible later use
        wagon = new List<PictureBox>();

        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Image = new Bitmap(game.Properties.Resources.SportwagonA);
        frm.Controls.Add(pb); // add created control to both the Form and our List
        wagon.Add(pb);

        pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Image = new Bitmap(game.Properties.Resources.SportwagonB);
        frm.Controls.Add(pb);
        wagon.Add(pb);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        foreach(PictureBox pb in wagon)
        {
            int x = rnd.Next(100);
            int y = rnd.Next(100);
            pb.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh i gonna try that but .later (might be tomorrow), i 've been trying to get that to work earlier, but must have made some typo or so, I hope thats the right way to do it.

Comment: I'm getting a system.NullReferenceException in  `racecar.add(pb)` its strange since the line before it `frm.Controls.Add(pb)` works fine

Comment: Hm got it working but not sure why, i created an array instead of a list in the class. The array points to the same pb, and i can alter positions using pb, kinda strange if you think about it as if i'm accessing it like pointers in c++ but it works now

Answer (score 0):

define your `picturebox array` as `static`

```
 public static PictureBox[] wagon;
```

then you can reach it with your class name from other class like

```
public class Main:Form  
{

  public Main()
  {
     bgcar.wagoon // and something happens
  }
}
```

This is what I see
[image]

Comment: inside class bgcar i made "public static PictureBox[]" but it doesnt seam to work ?

Comment: i just wanted to show that you can access your `picturebox array` inside your `main` class via your `bgcar` class

Answer (score 0):

So your `racecars` class is basically useless in the way you use it. Creating a new `PictureBox` instance each time gives you nothing. You have to add those to the form ( or other parent control ) which will draw them inside.

```
racecars = new bgcar();
racecars.update();
foreach(PictureBox pBox in racecars.wagon)
{
    this.Controls.Add(pBox);
}
```

Comment: i only want to instance it once in Main, then after that call the`racecars.update` method on the class to update all their settings and adjust their locations. Wont your foreach keep adding pictures ?.

Comment: For now you're just creating objects. You have to attach them to some parent control or form in order for them to be drawn on the screen. This code ensures that they will be added for the drawing after the update call.

Comment: i'd like to have the bgcar class image array[ ] and control by a call to update, so it displays images on the Main form. Currently it hangs on 2 parts the assignment of resourcefile based pictures, and updating the picture to the main form, your aprouch is different in that it pulls the images out of the bgcar class. (but my error happens earlier images isnt loaded in my class, and i'm not sure main should pull this from bgclass, thats the other way around.)